# Multer is uploading file, but not populating req.files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm studying node.js for a school project and I can't figure out why my code won't work. Whenever I upload a form that contains text and a file, the req.body gets populated but the req.files doesn't

***server.js***

```
const multer = require('multer')
const bparser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bparser.urlencoded(settings.body_parser))
...
let multer_storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => { 
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, settings.multer.destination))
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

let multer_options = {
    storage: multer_storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (settings.multer.allowed_files.indexOf(file.mimetype) >= 0) 
            cb(null, true)

        cb(null, false)
    }
}

app.use(multer(multer_options).any())

app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {

    if (!req.session.user)
        if (req.cookies.user)
            req.session.user = req.cookies.user

    next()
})

for (let i = 0; i < settings.routes.length; i++) {
    app.use('/', require("./core/routers/" + settings.routes[i]))
}
...
```

***./core/routers/post.js***

```
const router = require('express').Router()
...
router.post('/post/share/', (req, res) => {

    let data = {
        title: req.body.title,
        user: req.session.user,
        post: req.files[0].path,
        tags: req.tags.split(" ")
    }

    post.create(data).then((result) => {
        return result
    })
})
```

I keep encountering a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `cb(null, false)` in your `fileFilter` method, you tell multer that it shouldn't process the file, but it will still enter your middleware with: `req.files` being `undefined` that's why you get that error.

If you don't want it to enter to your middleware if the file wasn't processed, then you should pass an error to the callback instead:

```
let multer_options = {
    storage: multer_storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (settings.multer.allowed_files.indexOf(file.mimetype) >= 0) 
            return cb(null, true); // this return is missing

        cb(new Error('Invalid file'));
    }
}
```

In any case, you're missing a `return` statement before `cb(null, true);` otherwise you're calling twice the callback, once with `true` and the other once with `false`

---

To sum up, if you don't pass an `Error` to the `fileFilter` function, you should check for the presence of `req.files` in your middleware.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try the code below:

```
var tmp_path = req.file.path;
```